# Is there a way to not encounter captcha in selenium in python (changing user agent doesn't work)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I visit a particular website from my main browser, I don't get any captcha but when I do it from selenium, I'm getting ReCaptcha.

Is there a way to make the website think that selenium is my main browser or something like that?

I asked the same question previously but it was closed. However, I found a similar question that suggests changing the user agent. I tried implementing that but in my case, it doesn't work.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've just copied and pasted your last question and kept the same mistake: "**Is there a way to make the website think that selenium is my main browser or something like that?**" -  Why would you want "**to make the website think that selenium is my main browser**", if it only shows the captcha when you're using selenium? There was a reason why your previous question was closed and it stands:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As a side note, using a google webcache url, seems to avoid ReCaptcha to be displayed, i.e.: `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.naukri.com/jobs-in-andhra-pradesh`

Comment: @CONvid19 I want "to make the website think that selenium is my main browser" because I didn't get captcha in my main browser so I somehow make it think that selenium is the same as my main browser I wonldn't be prompted with a captcha.

Comment: @CONvid19 I really need the live version for my objective a chached version won't be enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try passing cookie of that website to selenium driver. Selenium always creates a fresh browser instance so it would not keep any trackers/cookies, that's why captcha is appearing.

Since I do not know how the website tracks that so above solution may not work. If so try creating a new firefox profile and login to that website manually. Then make sure captcha is not appearing for that profile. After that try using the same firefox profile for the automation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried the same with chrome but it didn't work. Ill try with firefox and get back to you